# New user registration on ejabberd server using jaber.net

Tags: c#, xmpp, instant-messaging, ejabberd

I'm working on an online text chat program in C#.Net. For this I'm using ejabberd server and for build a client I'm using jabber.net. But I'm facing some problem during the new user registration. Can anyone give me a proper code for register new user or some advice or instruction to create new account?

Comment: Please provide details of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [example](https://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/source/browse/trunk/Example/MainForm.cs).  You've got the right idea, but wait until OnConnect fires before calling Register().

Answer (score -1):

For make client used dll - [jaber-net](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/)

my code for new registration is given below :

```
            JID jid = new JID(txtName.Text, ServerName,Resource);
                jClient.User = txtName.Text;
                jClient.Password = txtNewPwd.Text;


                jClient.Connect();
                jClient.Register(jid);
                jClient.AutoLogin = false;

                jClient.Close(true);

                jClient.OnLoginRequired += new bedrock.ObjectHandler(jc_OnLoginRequired);

                jClient.OnRegisterInfo += new RegisterInfoHandler(this.jc_OnRegisterInfo);
                jClient.OnRegistered += new IQHandler(jc_OnRegistered);
```

But when I run this code:
Sometimes it executes all the events OnLoginRequired,OnRegisterInfo and OnRegistered
and sometimes no events execute

Comment: You should edit your original question to include this information.